# Возрастающая нумерация строк таблицы значений 1С УТ при очистке и повторном заполнении

Tags: sql-server, 1с

Есть таблица значений в форме обработки, заполняется запросом. Задача в том, что необходимо оставлять текущей строку после обновления данных в таблице значений. То есть выбрана, допустим, третья строка, таблица обновляется и фокус встаёт на ту же самую третью строку. Пытался делать так

```
текСтр = Элементы.Таблица.ТекущаяСтрока;   
//обновляю таблицу, заполняя её заново   
Элементы.Таблица.ТекущаяСтрока = текСтр;
```

Так вот, проблема в том, что номер строки постоянно инкрементируется при обновлении, соответственно после обновления он уже не тот, что до обновления. При чём инкрементируется на число, равное количеству строк в таблице. Такое подозрение, что метод `Очистить`, которым я очищаю таблицу перед новым заполнением, выполняет `DELETE`, а не `TRUNCATE` и номера строк являются автоинкрементными ключами. СУБД SQL Server.

Что это, баг или фича и как это победить?

Comment: текСтр = Элементы.Таблица.ТекущаяСтрока;  << получаем именно Строку (объект Строка, Таблицы) не НОМЕР ! После очистки - естественно что такой строки (объекта) не существует

Comment: Вы уверены? Посмотрите документацию, получаем число. Ну и как бы отладчик этому не противоречит

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это фича. Если нужно позиционироваться на строке после перезаполнения талицы на сервере, делай так:

```
ИндексСтроки = ?(МояТаблица.Количество(), МояТаблица.Индекс(Элементы.МояТаблица.ТекущиеДанные), 0);
ПерезаполнитьТаблицуНаСервере();
Если МояТаблица.Количество() Тогда
    СтрокаТаблицы = МояТаблица[ИндексСтроки];
    Элементы.МояТаблица.ТекущаяСтрока = СтрокаТаблицы.ПолучитьИдентификатор();  
КонецЕсли;
```

Comment: Спасибо, попробую. А про природу этой фичи можете подробнее рассказать?

Comment: Все просто, ваши подозрения были верными. Для новых элементов коллекции идентификатор присваивается автоинкрементом. Отсюда следует, что индекс элемента в коллекции может не совпадать с идентификатором элемента.


    Выдержка из СП:
    ДанныеФормыЭлементКоллекции (FormDataCollectionItem)
    ПолучитьИдентификатор (GetID)
    Синтаксис:
    ПолучитьИдентификатор() 

    Возвращаемое значение:
    Тип: Число. 
    Описание:

    Получает идентификатор для элемента коллекции. Этот идентификатор не привязан к позиции элемента в коллекции.